# Check if element contains another one in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I found many related things on Stack Overflow but not applicable for my case.

It's all in this exemple, I need to check if an element contains another one, and if yes, append something.

```
$(".bt_repondre").click(function(){
    comment = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    //I want to check if comment contains a .comment_full element, if no, append.
    comment.append('add');
});
```

Hope you can help me, I tried so many things...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just use `.find()` and check if returns an element, like this:

```
$(".bt_repondre").click(function(){
    comment = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    if (! comment.find('.comment_full').length) {
       comment.append('add');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Jean-François You really should check out Blender's answer! It's a little more concise than this one

Comment: PS: Don't use `.parent().parent().parent()`. Use `.closest(".someSelector")`

Comment: .parent().parent().parent() you can use parentsUntil("some_selector")

Answer (score 45):

You can use `.has` and `.length`:

```
if (comment.has('.comment_full').length) {
    // It has that element
}
```

- `.find` will iterate over all of the descendants, but `.has` will stop once a descendant that matches the selector has been found. It might run faster.
- `.length` just checks to see if the length of the resulting set of elements is non-zero.

Answer (score 12):

Most of these answers are incorrect.  You **must** pass a DOM node not a jQuery element for $.contains to work properly per https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/.

For example, this is how you would determine if `$('#a')` contains `$('#b)`.

> HTML:

```
<div id="a">
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

> JavaScript:

```
var $a = $('#a');
var $b = $('#b');
var contains = $.contains($a.get(0), $b.get(0));
console.log('contains', contains);
// outputs `true`
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of these answers are great, but there's a [new method called `contains(container,contained)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) (added in 1.4) that returns a [`Boolean`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Boolean)! It does basically the same thing as Blender's code snippet but is probably quicker, both to type and to execute.

Implemented in your code, it'd look like this:

```
$(".bt_repondre").click(function(){
    comment = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    if(!$.contains(comment, $('.comment_full')))//same as if(!jQuery.contains(...
    {
        comment.append('add');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you were looking let's say any tr element inside table with id of myTable you can use following code:

```
if($('#productsTableBody tr').length)
{
//...
}
```

This way we can check wheather table contains any row.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 comment.has('a.comment_full').length == 0
```

Comment: Wouldn't that tell you if it _didn't_ contain the other element?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for me:

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
    // if popup is visible
    if($('.assignment_popup:visible').length) {
        
        popup_id = $('.assignment_popup:visible').attr('id');

        // if user clicked on popup itself or on something inside popup then do nothing
        if($(e.target).hasClass('open-popup') || $(e.target).hasClass('assignment_popup')) {
            return;
        }

        // if clicked element is not inside the popup then close the popup
        if(!$('#' + popup_id).find(e.target).length) {
            $('#' + popup_id).fadeOut(500);
        }
    }
        
    //console.log(e.target);
});
```